# Trying to put 2 divs with an image and text next to each other

Tags: html, css

so I really tried using float and inline to align my boxes next to each other.

Here is an example of what I have.
[image]

What I am trying to do is move the CSS section with the information next to the HTML section.

Here is my html and css files for these parts.

```css
/* SECOND SECTION */
.content2 {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.content2 img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
}

.content2 h3,
.content2 p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

/* THIRD SECTION */
.content3 {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.content3 img {
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: right;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
}

.content3 h3,
.content3 p {
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!--SECOND SECTION-->
<div class="content2">
  <img src="./resources/images/html.jpeg" alt="">
  <h2>HTML</h2>
  <p>HTML (HyperText Markup Language) is used to give content to a web page and instructs web browsers on how to structure that content.</p>
</div>

<!--THREE SECTION-->
<div class="content3">
  <img src="./resources/images/css.jfif" alt="">
  <h2>CSS</h2>
  <p>CSS, or Cascading Style Sheets, is a language that is used in combination with HTML that customizes how HTML elements will appear. CSS can define styles and change the layout and design of a sheet.</p>
</div>
```

I tried finding the answer, sorry if its an easy fix. I just couldn't get it to work and I am very new to coding. Thank you.

Comment: Never use floats for design. You got `flex-boxes` and `grid` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap both in a div and use flexbox:

```css
/* SECOND SECTION */

body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.content2 {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.content2 img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
}

.content2 h3,
.content2 p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}


/* THIRD SECTION */

.content3 {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 50%;
}

.content3 img {
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: right;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
}

.content3 h3,
.content3 p {
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="content2">
    <img src="./resources/images/html.jpeg" alt="">
    <h2>HTML</h2>
    <p>HTML (HyperText Markup Language) is used to give content to a web page and instructs web browsers on how to structure that content.</p>
  </div>
  <!--THREE SECTION-->
  <div class="content3">
    <img src="./resources/images/css.jfif" alt="">
    <h2>CSS</h2>
    <p>CSS, or Cascading Style Sheets, is a language that is used in combination with HTML that customizes how HTML elements will appear. CSS can define styles and change the layout and design of a sheet.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked!! really appreciate it! Gonna implement this into future projects.